# How to extract data from 'edit my profile' page in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, profiles

I m trying to extract the firstname and lastname fields of a user whose email-id I know, and I m trying to display those in a backend page using a plugin, can someone please give me a short code for that, I just can,t find where these values are stored

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
     $user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );/*$user gives you all data*/
     $first_name = $user->first_name;/*$first_name gives you first name*/
     $last_name = $user->last_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shortcode to do it, you can define the shortcode this way in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
<?php 
function custom_user_func( $atts ) {
    $user= $atts['email'];
    $user_info = get_user_by( 'email', $user );
    $username = $user_info->user_login;
    $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
    $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
    return "First name = {$first_name}, Last name = {$last_name}, Username = {$username}";
}
add_shortcode( 'customuser', 'custom_user_func' ); 
?>
```

Then, simply use `[customuser email="email@example.com"]` wherever you want to show these information. You can modify the output the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's details by user's email using `function get_user_by()`.
To get Firstname and Lastname you can user following snippet:

```
<?php
   $user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
   echo 'User is ' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
?>
```

Hope this solution will help you.